# Find the polar form of $12 + 5i$

Tags: complex-numbers, polar-coordinates

Polar form: $\vert z \vert \big(\cos\theta + i\sin\theta \big)$

$$\begin{aligned}z^2 &= \vert 12^2 + 5^2 \vert\\
z &= \vert 13 \vert \\
\arctan \frac{5}{12} &= 22.61^\circ\\
z &= |13| \big(\cos(22.61^\circ) + i\sin(22.61^\circ)\big)\end{aligned}$$

Up until now my textbook has only shown answers with $\theta$ being in radian form. Is it acceptable to write the polar form with $\theta$ in degrees like what I did above?

Comment: It should be noted that $arctan(5/12)$ is **approximately** $22.6^o$

Comment: @EvanKim Be careful, this $z^2 = \vert 12^2 + 5^2 \vert$ is wrong. Similarly $z=|13|.$

Answer (score 1):

Writing the polar form using degrees instead of radians is legitimate, but not recommended. Radians are the better choice overall: one of the main reason being that they are plain numbers (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensionless_quantity) whereas degrees have a physical dimension.

That said, your notation is wrong. I corrected it:

$$|z|^2 = \vert 12^2 + 5^2 \vert$$
$$|z| = 13 $$
$$\theta=\arctan\left(\frac{5}{12}\right) = 22.61^\circ$$
$$z = 13 \big(\cos(22.61^\circ) + i\sin(22.61^\circ)\big)$$

Comment: How would you convert $22.61^\circ$ to radians?

Comment: It is equivalent to $\frac{22.61}{180}\pi$ radians

Comment: oh okay, I thought you had to do 22.61/180 and write that as the answer. Your answer doesn't look very messy at all

Answer (score 1):

Of course it's fine; degrees and radians are just different ways of representing the same quantity. It's just that radians are more usually used due to various reasons. See [this expository article](https://www.ddm.fmph.uniba.sk/ADUC/files/Issue5/06%20Kupkova.pdf) on the subject. Since $|13|=13$, you can also just write the result as $$13\cos 22.61^\circ+(13\sin 22.61^\circ)i.$$

Comment: @EvanKim In my opinion, if the form requested is $|z|(\cos\theta + i\sin\theta)$ then the intended answer is $|13|(12/13 + i5/13).$

Comment: @user2661923 usually, such questions ask to put a complex number given in polar in Cartesian form, which is $x+iy$. It's quite weird to have the magnitude put outside. It's even weirder to write $|13|$ when it can be immediately simplified to $13$. If the OP is requiring this particular form, then they will have to specify.

Comment: I was guided by the 1st line of the OP's query.  Absent that, my inclination would have been: $\;\theta\; =$ any angle whose cos is 12/13 and whose sin is 5/13, and the polar form is $\;13e^{i\theta}.$

Comment: How would you convert $22.61^\circ$ to radians?

Comment: @EvanKim $180^\circ=\pi$. Hence $1^\circ=\pi/180$, so...